# how to close window form which is hosting WPF user control from within a WPF user control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want to close a window form that is hosting a WPF user control. Something like this as used while closing a current form in window application. But for WPF application I am not able to get reference to user controls parent

How to get Form which is hosting this control so that I can close my form

this.Close()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add to your WpfControl property

```
public Form FormsWindow { get; set; }
```

In your WinForm add event handler for `ElementHost`'s event `ChildChanged`:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration; 

public MyForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
    elementHost.ChildChanged += ElementHost_ChildChanged;
}
void ElementHost_ChildChanged(object sender, ChildChangedEventArgs e) {
    var ctr = (elementHost.Child as UserControl1);
    if (ctr != null)
        ctr.FormsWindow = this;
}
```

After that you can use the `FormsWindow` property of your WpfControl to manipulate window. Example:

```
this.FormsWindow.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is correct, but it seems we must set child after  **InitializeComponent();**

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution could be,

```
 Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
 parent.Close();
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the WPF usercontrol is hosting inside a windows forms.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to @The_Smallest's otherwise very clear answer.

If you just copy and past the event handler code, you will still need to set your Forms's ChildChanged event to ElementHost_ChildChanged.  I missed that step and spent 30 minutes trying to figure out why FormsWindow was null.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the Form object of the MyControl class already. We have in it a Form field to which we pass an instance object open Form. Having an assigned object we can freely manipulate it (including also call the function `form.Close ();`

WPF Control (with XAML):

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public Form form = null;

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(HandleEsc);
    }

    private void HandleEsc(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            form.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Form:

```
public class MainForm
{
    //...

    public Form form = null;

    public MainForm(MyControl myControl)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //...
        myControl.form = (Form)this;
    }
}
```